# How can I install Unity Player for Tor Browser 3.6.3?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

I have Tor Browser 3.6.3 (secure browser based on Firefox 24.7.0).
I want to run Unity3d game like : https://apps.facebook.com/dragons_world/

I've installed Unity Player promted, but it doesn`t appears on Tor restart.
What should I do?

Comment: This may pose an anonymity risk. Such plugins are basically separate programs with lots of privileges on your system, more than what your browser usually allows.

Answer (score 1):

Tor does not support, nor will support any additional plugins for the browser.  I asked this questing a few months ago, and they dolt me the same thing.

Now, you can try [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/976357). I have no clue what registry tor takes, but I would guess that it is somewhat similar to the one firefox occupies.